# Delphi7 + ZeosDB date format error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, zeos

I'm using Delphi 7 and ZeosDB on a application that connect to a Firebird and a SQL Server database but I'm with a problem when the field is date format. On Firebird work normally but when I change the connect to SQL Server the error is showed anything similar to "field is not of expected format". Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

The problem was related to a difference between firebird and SQL Server. My firebird database use sql dialect 3 and I suposed that the dialect of SQL Server is different. I resolved after modify my date fields on databases from datetime to timestamp.

The timestamp of dialect 3 is equivalent to datetime of dialect 1.